# Jquery Validation Plugin addMethod with Localization

Tags: jquery, validation

I read this into jquery website:

> message (Optional) String, Function
>   The default message to display for
>   this method. Can be a function created
>   by jQuery.validator.format(value).
>   When undefined, an already existing
>   message is used (handy for
>   localization), otherwise the
>   field-specific messages have to be
>   defined.

I have added a method like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("postalCode", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9\-]+$/i.test(value);
});
```

Then, on my localization file I have:

```
postalCode: jQuery.validator.format("blabla")
```

However, "blabla" is never assumed.

I've also tried to pass jQuery.format() as a message argument:

```
$.validator.addMethod("postalCode", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9\-]+$/i.test(value);
}, jQuery.format());
```

No luck either.

How is this suppose to work?

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("postalCode", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9\-]+$/i.test(value);
```

Should work. If you omit the message, it will get that message from your localization message file.

Great class here. :)

Comment: I searched for more complicated way and you have the soluce ... so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In method $.validator.addMethod() the last optional param is a default constant message as text in quots. You have to use  jQuery.validator.format("... {0}...{1}...") instead in case the defined handler has parameters:

```
addMethod("methodName", function(value, element, params){
```

which can be outputed in error message, replacing the mask "{N}" (here is why function "format" needed for), where N is the number of parameter if there are several of them passed. 
For i.g. rule "minlength:10" means that the "10" is a value of the third variable in handler func.

If you do not specify a default message, then it can be defined in section "messages":

```
,messages : {
   someField1 : {methodName:"error message"},
   someField2 : {methodName:$.validator.messages.custom_mess}
}
```

It is desired to include js code in the following sequence:

1. "validate" plugin
2. "addMethod" instructions
3. "localization" file
4. your onLoad code with $('#someForm').validate({...})

Answer (score 0):

If you want e.g. "customPassword" validation.

1. Make .js files whit locale code on end (messages_en.js, messages_de.js).
2. Include file depending of chosen app language.
3. Add translation messages like this:

```js
$.extend( $.validator.messages, {
 customPassword: "One number, small and big letter and min 8 chars.",
 required: "This field is required.",
 remote: "Please fix this field."
});
```

4. Then add method whit second parameter "$.validator.messages.customPassword" instead of string message.

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("customPassword", function(value, element, params){
    return this.optional(element) || (value.match(/((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,50})/));
}, $.validator.messages.customPassword);
```